# Writing a Dynamically built HTML to a file in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#

I have a web form which takes in user information. The value of various text boxes is used to build a html file. I write this html to a file( with specific name) and then prompt user to Save this file.This html is used for creating outlook email signatures. Currently I have this html within the application.This has been deployed to the server. I had to set write permission on this file for all users for it to work.

Are there any security risks? What happens if multiple users access this applications and write to the file at the same time.

Comment: Show us the relevant code!

Answer (score 0):

When you say the file has "a specific name", do you mean that it is always the same name? If so, then yes, there will be problems if multiple users use this functionality at the same time. They'll be overwriting the one file and downloading each other's data. You would need to generate a unique filename each time the process runs to avoid this.

But do you actually need to save the file?

Or is your goal purely to produce some HTML for the user to download, and the way you are doing this is by writing it to a file, and then prompting them to download that file?

If you don't need to save the file, but rather just need to generate HTML and prompt the user to save, just serve it up as a normal page, and set response headers such that their browser will download it. Something along these lines:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=my_file.html");
```

Comment: Yes, the file will have the same name. I do not actually have to save the file. The html file has to have proper format to be used as email signature.That is the reason I am building a string of HTML based on the input and writing to a file.

Comment: My current code is - Note: I have constructed and wrote html to file Email_sig.html.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the user fills the web form and submits. Immediately, an html file pops up for download from the server. I think this is very neat implementation of this scenario. You just need to make sure that resources are released properly in order to prevent locking of files.

When multiple users access this application, it should not break since separate files are created with a specific name (as you have mentioned). I don't know what logic has been used to create unique names. At some peculiar situation (this is purely dependent on your name calculation logic) if the calculated specific file name somehow becomes similar to an existing file, you should have code in place to replace or create a different version of the same file name. Locking could occur if you are writing captured data from web form into the same file again and again without disposing your stream/File objects . Make sure you dispose your objects after use in the code.

It would be great if you give access to the application pool of the web application to a user who has write access to that file/folder instead of giving everyone the write access. In this way, your application gets full rights to perform write operations rather than users having rights. If users have write access on the file/folder, it is very easy for anyone to peek in and do something unexpected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Carson63000 - This what I am doing -  `String FileName = Server.MapPath("Email_SIG.html"); String FilePath = Server.MapPath("Email_SIG.html");    String sPath = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
            System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "text/html";  response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sPath + ";");   response.WriteFile(sPath);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();`